# Would it be unethical to claim affiliation when it was not made official yet?

Tags: graduate-school, ethics, affiliation

I received an acceptance letter to a Master's Program. The official enrollment will be in one month. Until then I am not officially in the program yet.

I am about to finish a paper and I want to submit it to a conference. Would it be unethical to claim affiliation in my paper in this situation?

Comment: Can you put in your previous affiliation?

Comment: Mention your former affiliation, because the paper credit must goes to the university with which you were affiliated, not the new university.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Affiliation should indicate the institution with which you were affiliated while doing the work and writing the paper.  If the paper was already finished before you started at an institution, then don't list it; use your previous affiliation instead (or "none" if you weren't affiliated with any institution).

If you end up making significant revisions to the paper after enrolling at the new institution, then you could consider listing both it and your previous institution.

If it matters, I wouldn't necessarily use the "official enrollment" date to decide when affiliation starts, but rather the date when you actually started attending classes, using the institution's facilities, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Just my two cents (I really need a new opening line)

This would be completely unethical.

Think of it this way.  If you only had all the credits to earn a degree, and had gone through the graduation process but had not yet been officially awarded said degree, would you go ahead and list said degree as an earned degree?

Comment: This is just an assertion followed by an analogy, with no real indication of how the analogy connects to the actual situation. Reason about why claiming this affiliation would be "completely unethical"; don't just list other things that you think would also be completely unethical.

Comment: @DavidRicherby You forgot to add "in my opinion."

Comment: "This would be completely unethical" is an assertion: it's a claim that something is true. The text after "Think of it this way" is an analogy: it doesn't talk about the actual situation (claiming an affiliation before starting a course) but about a situation you feel is similar (claiming a degree before it's been awarded). Which part of your post is the "real indication of how the analogy connects to the actual situation"?

Comment: Started the answer with the in my opinion statement, by saying "just my two cents."    Also, I should not have to hold one's hands and connect the dots for them every time I answer something.   Analogies are useful in communication.  In actuality, how can any one person make a call about if something is truly ethical or not.  It comes down to the person asking the question to make that decision.